# iOS Calendar application shows old home address as home address

Tags: ios, contacts, calendar

I have this issue for a long time in **iOS**. But it's so annoying lately. Here is the situation, 5 months back I moved to new address. I changed my address in the contacts. When I try to create a new event and type 'home' in the address, it **shows the old address as a home address** and new address as '**John Doe Home**'. Same happens for work address. But my MacBook shows it right. I use Gmail calendar in the calendar app. Is there a way to fix this? I tried following solutions and nothing worked so far

1. Unlinked my Facebook
2. Deleted home address and added again
3. Removed home address from significant locations in the Privacy section
4. Checked Gmail calendar settings, everything looks good

Answer (score 1):

It seems they fixed this issue in iOS12